# How to save state of selected rows in tableView inside segmentedController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview

I have a segmented controller with two segments. Each segment has one common tableView.
How can I save selected cells when switching segments? Could you please give some idea how to achieve it?

I can save only one selected row when switching segments.

ViewModel

```
var years: [String] = []
var genres: [String] = []

var selectedGenr: Int?
var selectedYear: Int?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        if viewModel.selectedGenr == indexPath.row {
            viewModel.selectedGenr = nil
        } else {
            viewModel.selectedGenr = indexPath.row
        }
    } else {
        if viewModel.selectedYear == indexPath.row {
            viewModel.selectedYear = nil
        } else {
            viewModel.selectedYear = indexPath.row
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    
}
```

}

Comment: I think the issue is with your view hierarchy. If there's a "shared" table view, shouldn't it be *above* the segmented control? And if it belongs to both segments, shouldn't there be *two* table views (with the same data source) in each segment? I can post code for either if needed.

Comment: It sounds like you have named `UISegmentedControl` 'segmentedControl' for yourself.  Whatever you call it, where does 'segmentedControl' come from?  Where is its `IBOutlet` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store selection as a list in the view model
then in table view

### pseudo-code

```
if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
if viewModel.selectedYears.contains(indexPath.row) {
viewModel.selectedYears.remove(indexPath.row)
}
else {
viewModel.selectedYears.append(indexPath.row)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got your idea. Solved selection state task this way

Answer (score 0):

```
if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            if self.selectedIndexesForGenres.contains(indexPath.row) {
                if let index = self.selectedIndexesForGenres.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
                                self.selectedIndexesForGenres.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        } else {
                            self.selectedIndexesForGenres.append(indexPath.row)
                        }
            }
        else {
            if self.selectedIndexesForYears.contains(indexPath.row) {
                if let index = self.selectedIndexesForYears.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
                                self.selectedIndexesForYears.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        } else {
                            self.selectedIndexesForYears.append(indexPath.row)
                        }
            }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```